# Error in AWS Redshift while calculating a difference between two dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When I add `LIMIT TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1` in my query, I'm getting this issue:

```
ERROR: Not implemented
DETAIL:
error: Not implemented
code: 1001
context: 'IsA(cons,Const)' - 
query: 1621055
location: xen_execute.cpp:1077
process: padbmaster pid=10863
```

So, as you can see, there is not a good error information that can help me to solve the issue.

That LIMIT should be the difference between "date to" and "date from" plus 1.
So, if I replace that LIMIT for just `LIMIT 8` (for example), it works perfectly.

This query should be executed in Redshift and in a PostgreSQL, so, functions like DATEDIFF won't be useful, due to DATEDIFF is not implemented in PostgreSQL :/

In case it can help you, I saw another guys dealing with some similar issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=239872

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "due to DATEDIFF is not implemented in PostgreSQL :/"

Postgres (specially Redshift) implements datediff function. It's just the format that is different.

```
datediff(d,start_date,end_date)
```

where `d : days`

Remember, do not use operators for the datatype they are not meant to be. Using arithmetic operators ( + / - ) on dates will throw weird results at times and can be catastrophic.